# Add a custom country field option to country_select ruby on rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu

I'm currently using the country_select gem for ruby on rails:
https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select

The following code prints a list of all the countries:

```
<%= f.country_select :CountryTo, html_options = {:class => "form-control"} %>
```

I want to add a custom option field in the select dropdown with the value "Anywhere".
Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I am pretty new with Ruby on rails so my apologies if there is a super easy fix, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [tests of `country_select`](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select/blob/fad7c1d4aa24af9c84b1718176392d56f201a1f3/spec/country_select_spec.rb#L161) it supports the `include_blank`-option of `select_tag`. So you should be able to use:

```
<%= f.country_select(:country_to, include_blank: 'Anywhere') %>
```

Please consider also having a look at the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Answer (score 1):

Just add, for example, this initializer:

```rb
# config/initializers/00_add_countries.rb

require 'countries'

ISO3166::Data.register(
  alpha2: 'ww',
  name: 'World',
  translations: {
    'en' => 'World',
    'de' => 'Welt',
    'fr' => 'Monde'
  }
)

ISO3166::Country.new('ww').name == 'World'
```